# Log IP of request causing a decodeURIComponent error

Tags: node.js, http

I now get this error in my NodeJS server's logs:

```
[2021-11-13T14:43:45.107Z] URIError: Failed to decode param '/cgi-bin/%%32%65%%32%65/bin/sh'
    at decodeURIComponent (<anonymous>)
    at decode_param (~/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:172:12)
    at Layer.match (~/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:123:27)
    at matchLayer (~/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:574:18)
    at next (~/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:220:15)
    at expressInit (~/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/init.js:40:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (~/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (~/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at ~/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (~/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (~/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at query (~/node_modules/express/lib/middleware/query.js:45:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (~/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (~/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at ~/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (~/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
```

It seems related to [Apache's path traversal vulnerability](https://blog.qualys.com/vulnerabilities-threat-research/2021/10/27/apache-http-server-path-traversal-remote-code-execution-cve-2021-41773-cve-2021-42013). My server does not run Apache but I would still like to blacklist the IP address. This request does not print to the logs, and does not call my app's code in `app.js`.

How can I log the IP of the request?